# How would you change the default Android boot animation?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, boot-animation

I am attempting to change my boot animation on a rooted Xoom with Android 3.2.

I've got the files in part0/ the desc.txt looks like

```
1408 880 24
p 0 0 part0
```

I made the images 512x256 since this is what the Honeycomb boot animation had.

After I copy the bootanimation.zip image to /system/media/ and reboot I get just a black screen. I've tried 777 and 644 permissions on this file.

Any ideas how to not get a black screen?

Comment: Closely related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/how-to-create-a-custom-boot-animation

Comment: this may or may not attract more attention on StackOverflow.com

Comment: This isn't on-topic for [so].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a corrupt zip problem.. from linux zip tool you must be using the -0 switch to 'store'.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Don't forget to "accept" this answer to act as a signpost for future readers with this problem.